# Ansible/Yaml -- conditionally become another user

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following use case. A user runs an ansible play book and provides a user (with -e user=). In the playbook, as expected, I do become and become_user. However, I want to do this only when the username provided differs from his own username (which is statically known).

I tried to conditionally include a file, where I will do the become, but this didn't seem to work so far.

Here is some of my code:

First/playbook file:

```
---
- name: example
hosts: examplehost
tasks:
  - include: "usersetup.yml"
    when: "{{ user }} != {{ user_id }}"
```

Second file (usersetup.yml)

I am unclear about the format of this file, since I am relatively new to the process, but I currently have:

```
- become: yes
- become_user: "{{ user }}"
```

This doesn't work of course, so any ideas/suggestions welcome. I would be more than happy to provide more clarifications if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I am posting my own solution for anyone else who may encounter the same situation.

Basically, here is the syntax in the playbook to conditionally become another user.

```
become: "{{ 'no' if user == ansible_user else 'yes' }}"
become_user: "{{ edge_user }}"
```

The condition can be whatever you want. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Also, to *become* a user on the remote host that's different than the local user running Ansible:

```
become: "{{ 'no' if user == lookup('env', 'USER') else 'yes' }}"
become_method: sudo
become_user: "{{user}}"
```

Hope it helps.